# rails mail-merge sort of functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, customization, actionmailer

I have a scenario in which i'm required to allow the user to send a message to multiple recipients but the user can also customize the message for each user by using a text editor. Now i know action-mailer allow multiple recipients but i'm wondering how am i supposed to handle the customized messages for each user and then sending them over.?

Are there any plugins or gems available to help support this functionality...or what else could be the solution for this??? please suggest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send the emails one by one - you cannot customize the contents per receiver when sending out one single email to several receivers. This is how email works.
Instead what you should do is to store the customizations somewhere, and when the email sending is triggered, you cycle through the list of receivers, check if there are any customizations for him/her, build the email accordingly and send it out.

Answer (score 1):

how about send to them one by one?

Answer (score 0):

there must be something like bcc which is available generally it can be done by the help of bcc however there is no way except that in my opinion.